# Ember StateManager does not find controller

Tags: ember.js

I have tried my bit searching through StackOverflow for some answer, but could not locate. Refer below the following code snippet - Ember stateManager is unable to find the controller instance. Also the view code is not rendered also, please guide me as to the mistakes made.

```
Dashboard.stateManager = Ember.StateManager.create({
start: Ember.State.extend({
    controller: null,

    enter: function(manager) {
        this.controller = manager.get('indexController');
        this.setPath('view.controller', this.controller);
        console.log(this.controller);
    },

    view: Dashboard.MapView

})
});
Dashboard.initialize(Dashboard.stateManager);
Dashboard.stateManager.transitionTo('start');
```

The Dashboard.MapView is complex, it looks like

```
Dashboard.MapView = Ember.View.extend({
...
)};
```

Do I have to add something so that view gets executed? Why is statemanager unable to get 'indexController') - console output returns undefined in the console log line in this snippet, although Dashboard.IndexController is defined after the page is loaded and so is Dashboard.stateManager.

Please note that the app is single-page, so I have not defined routes at all, although IndexController is defined. Could this be a problem? But the app does not say 'route undefined' etc., but the page is blank? Is this the right way to define a StateManager for a single-page app without any routes other than "/"?

Thanks,
Paddy

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a recent version of Ember, I think the way to get your controller for a stateManager used in place of router would be:

```
manager.get('container').lookup('controller:index')
```

Comment: Hi,<br/> I tried this, but it is still giving undefined for manager.get('container'), do I have to provide further details about my page layout or anything else?

Comment: Found the answer in this [page](http://www.akshay.cc/blog/2013-02-22-debugging-ember-js-and-ember-data.html), but my view is still not rendering.

Comment: StateManagers do not have anything special to understand a "view" property. I think you may be looking at rather old info about ViewStates perhaps?

Comment: The tutorials I saw are all showing ViewState, what is its alternative, as it has been deprecated? Can you send me any links to some examples of the new way.

Comment: Hi Paddy, using the router is the golden path for recent releases of Ember.

Comment: If I want to build a single-page app where the individual screens should not be accessible, won't the router approach expose each screen as separate URL ? Or is it that the router approach along with "location: none" will be the solution?

Comment: router with location: none would do it